# My simple code doesn't work with express-validator

Tags: node.js, express

I am studying about express-validator.
'router.post' passes without the validation
I made form and password input in html.

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello Guys!</h1>
    <p>Fill in your id number.</p>
    <form action="/yournumber/sub" method="POST">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <button type="submit">Summit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

And that password call router.post
This is my router code.
but this post runs redirect regardless of the length of password.
How could I make correctly?

```
    router.post('/yournumber/sub', (req, res, next) => {
    req.check('password').isLength({min: 4});

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
      req.session.errors = errors;
      req.session.success = false;
      console.log('error');
    } else {
      req.session.success = true;
      console.log('suc')
    }

    res.redirect('/ab');
});
```

Comment: There are other validation packages that are easier to use than express-validator. I have used [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) with minimum effort, [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) is another highly regarded validation package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the `req.check()`-notation and can't find it in the [official documentation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html), **but**:

The way I use this module is as an express middleware. You can check the snipped on the linked documentation. Here is your adapted code:

```
const validation = [
  check('password').isLength({min: 4})
];

router.post('/yournumber/sub', validation, (req, res, next) => {
  var errors = validationResult(req);
  if (errors.isEmpty()) {
    // valid
  } else {
    // not valid
  }
});
```

As you can see, the `validation`-array is passed in as another handler for the route. It works the same way as your handler:

1. Check if the parameter is valid, as specified to the `check()`-function
2. If not, add information to the `req`-object
3. Call `next()` to get to either the next validation or your handler.

Then, when you want to check the results, use `validationResult()` (which you spelled wrong and called as a method of `req` instead of passing it to the method).